# Matlab Parsing Error

Tags: matlab, parsing, variables, octave

Below is the MATLAB code that I am attempting to use, however I only have a copy of OCTAVE (and I know some functions do not translate to Octave).

I am getting a parser error, specifically:

ERROR:

```
Parser error near line 4
Syntax error [~,ix] = sort(S1);
```

For the below code...

```
function OUT = merge_two_solutions(S1,S2,w1,w2,vis)
if ~exist('w1','var'),w1=.5;w2=.5;end
ref = (1:length(S1));
[~,ix] = sort(S1);
S1n = S1; S1n(ix) = ref;
[~,ix] = sort(S2);
S2n = S2; S2n(ix) = ref;
OUT = w1*S1n+w2*S2n;
if exist('vis','var')
    clf;plot(S1n,S2n,'.b');
end
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766330/what-is-this-matlab-statement-for-m-n-sizeimge), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177229/ignoring-return-value-syntax), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100272/matlab-code-works-with-one-version-but-not-the-other), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913325/tilde-character-in-the-brackets-matlab-code), and probably others.

Comment: upgrade your Octave version. You must be using one of the 3.2.X, the last of which is more than 3 years old. If you are using any of the 3.4.X (which was released more than 2 years ago) or later, it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of Octave which does not support `~` for return-value dismissal. You should upgrade your octave version to at least 3.4.0 (released more than 2 years ago) for that feature. Alternatively, you can work around it with:

```
% don't care for value of TMP
[ TMP, ix ] = sort(S1);
...
[ TMP, ix ] = sort(S2);
```

You must using an Octave from the 3.2.X series or older. Note that there's been 8 releases since (2 major and 6 minor. And there's another major release being planned for sometime this summer).

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Now the error is _TMP_ is undefined near line 2 column 4.

Comment: You shouldn't use `TMP` in your code besides in those two occurrences in `[ TMP, ix ] ...` - remove other occurrences of `TMP`. And please, accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: For non-Matlab users, some [background](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/) and [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html) on what the tilde (`~`) operator is. Surprised that it still hasn't made its way into Octave (perhaps the developers just don't like the new syntax?).

Comment: @horchler that is not true. Octave does support that syntax since version 3.4.0 which was released more than 2 years ago.

Comment: @carandraug: ?? So the real answer to this question is that user needs upgrade their free software. I think that you that you should write this up as an answer.

Comment: @horchler yes. But I won't take credit for the current answer which identified the actual problem. I'll just edit the answer to add that note.

Comment: @carandraug Your suggested edit is valuable addition to the answer. How could I accept it in the way that you get the credit for it? You should maybe suggest another edit with the same contents and I will review it as *accepted*. I wasn't present on SO when last review happened, and some reviewers rejected it unrightfully.

Comment: I don't know about review edits. You're the original author of the answer, don't you have final say on what should be accepted? If not, just edit it yourself.

Comment: Your review was rejected by reviewers when I was not on SO, so I can't do anything about that one suggested edit. You should try to edit it one more time and I'll accept it. [HERE](http://pastebin.com/5tGFSpeE) are your changes.